# How to get differentiating gap between two tableview cells in a tableview?

Tags: ios, swift

I have tried this code but it didn't work for me:

```
let whiteBackgroundLayerView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10 , y: 8, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 20, height: 90))
whiteBackgroundLayerView.layer.backgroundColor = CGColor(colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), components: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.8])
whiteBackgroundLayerView.layer.masksToBounds = false
whiteBackgroundLayerView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteBackgroundLayerView)
cell.contentView.sendSubviewToBack(whiteBackgroundLayerView)
```

I want the output be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your custom cell, add the following code:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    contentView.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(contentView.frame, UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10))
}
```